# Question about making a Five Nights at Freddy's character

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm pretty new to Blender, but I'm trying to create some [Five Nights at Freddy's (FNaF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Nights_at_Freddy%27s_(video_game)) characters for a project of mine.

My question is: Should I create an endoskeleton first? And then use that endoskeleton when creating the different characters. Or should I just not create an endoskeleton? And just make the endoskeleton parts that I need for the different characters.

The [animatronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animatronics)/robot has an endoskeleton, which is basically like a human skeleton. The animatronic needs the endoskeleton to be able to stand and move around. So I must have it in my animatronic. But I don't know if should create the whole endoskeleton or if I should only make the endoskeleton parts that are visible from the outside.

I will try to create some animations, too, if that matters.

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Oh, I thought my title was good, but I guess not. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What do you mean by "endoskeleton"? Do you perhaps mean armature?

Comment: Well, the title says "Question about making fnaf character" - first of all, not everybody knows what "fnaf" is, so it is unclear if this is relevant for answering the question. Then, "question about making" - which task of making? Modeling, texturing, rigging, animating etc.?

Comment: Endoskeleton is the robot/animatronic's skeleton. It's what makes the robot/animatronics able to move. So the robot/animatronics that I am modeling need a endoskeleton. But I don't necessarily have to create the entire endoskeleton. I could make only the visible parts.

Comment: Is this better? 
Hello! I am currently modeling a animatronic for a project of mine. The animatronic has a endoskeleton, which is basically like a human skeleton. The animatronic need the endoskeleton to be able to stand and move around. So it's essential that I have it in my animatronic. But I don't know if should create the whole endoskeleton or if I should only make the endoskeleton parts that are visible from the outside. I'm not to familiar with blender, so I don't really know if it matters that I create the endoskeleton or not. I will try to create some animation too if that matters.

Comment: Your audience here is international, and  of various ages. :) That's not to say they can't help, but 'fnaf' may be completely meaningless to many of them. Please illustrate with a characteristic example. You can embed pictures in your post with the tools provided. Then folks would know what you mean by 'endoskeleton' too. BTW, if you want to animate your character, the endoskeleton (at least partial, where it can be seen) would be a good start, IMO

Comment: I didn't know what "fnaf" meant but I know the "Five Nights at Freddy's" animatronics although I've never played the game or watched the movie ;-) -- Basically, you don't need to model any parts that are located inside the model and are not visible from the outside. A sketch or reference image would be helpful to answer your question and for modeling. For animation/posing there are so-called *Armatures* in Blender. The armature is not rendered but works like a skeleton to move the model. The visible model is called *mesh* in Blender.

Comment: The wiki says *"An endoskeleton is a skeleton that is on the inside of a body, like humans, dogs, or some fish. "* - But that makes me wonder why there are *"endoskeleton parts that are visible from the outside"* (quote from your comment)....?

Comment: @Blunder The animatronic that I'm creating is supposed to be very old and beat up. So parts of it's suit will be destroyed or missing. Making the endoskeleton visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it as accurate as possible, you'll want the endo to be visible between the joints and anywhere someone might look closely (Which is nearly everywhere.) If you're rigging you could simply parent the suit pieces to the endoskeleton (rigging the endo first). It's up to you to decide if you want to take the extra time, but I say you should do it, as it may simplify later steps and create a more complete-looking final model.